# jQuery qtip plugin: old popup still appears behind new popup. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

This is jQuery 1.9.0. I use qTip 1.0.0-rc3, which I have stripped out of all `$.browser` code (since it has disappeared since 1.9.0). I attach a simple, bare bones (not even restyled for now) tip. The full function is below:

```
// Function to report a parse error
function reportParseError(parseError, msgHandle, textArea)
{
    // Find the inner link element -- there is only one, so this is "safe".
    var link = msgHandle.find("a");

    link.text("line " + parseError["line"]);

    // Add an onclick hook to the link. When clicking on the link, the caret
    // in the text area will move to the position of the error.
    link.on("click", function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        textArea.focus().setCursorPosition(parseError["offset"]);
    });

    link.qtip({
        content: parseError["message"],
        show: "mouseover",
        hide: "mouseout",
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: "topMiddle",
                tooltip: "bottomMiddle"
            }
        }
    });

    // Show the message
    msgHandle.show();
}
```

This function does what I want (the tip appears above the link).

The problem is when a previous content for the tip (parse messages can be quite big) was larger than the newer content: I am then seeing the old contents below the new ones on a mouseover (both contents disappear on mouseout).

How do you solve that?

**Edit**: after some more thinking about it, it appears that the observed behavior is expected: each time this function is triggered, a new tooltip is created. It means the tip would need to be attached at "init time" (ie, when document.ready()) and filled with an appropriate content when needed. Do I get this right?

Comment: You're seeing two qtips when hovering over the same element?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I suspect there are actually more than two and all old qtips still lie below, but I may be wrong.

Comment: What is `link` in your code? Where is that coming from?

Comment: It is a DOM elment of type `a`. I will paste more code.

Comment: Agree, use qTip 2. Also, I believe you need to attach qTip to each element individually: `link.each(function() { $(this).qtip(); });`

Comment: @matthewpavkov the link is one and only one element

Comment: @Juhana because I am a beginner with JavaScript and qtip 2 is not as well documented as 1 -- yet (edit: oops, didn't see the wiki)

Comment: You're making a new `div` for the qTip every time that `reportParseError()` runs. So, the old message is still in the DOM. When you hover over the link, you see all of the qTips attached to that link.

Comment: OK, so, let's say I am using qtip2: how do I attach a tip at load time and then change its contents?

Comment: @matthewpavkov I kind of figured out it was the case. The problem right now is I don't know how to avoid that in code.

Comment: Well, a simple approach would be to `destroy` the qtip each time it's hidden: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#destroy Then it'll be recreated each time. There's also a way to update the qTip's contents: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#updateContent

Comment: I'd rather go the second way... Though I cannot manage to get a handle for the qtip :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, answer to self.

I could not get qTip2 to work at all, so qTip 1 it is.

The problem was as I discovered, tooltips (divs, in fact) were created but never destroyed.

The solution was to create two dummy tooltips on document.ready(), an destroy them right before recreating them, since I was unable to grab a handle on the tooltips in order to update their contents.